# #2002 - Connection timed out The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a **MySQL** & [**phpMyAdmin**](https://phpmyadmin.net) on [**Replit**](https://replit.com) but there is an error when I'm trying to connect to it from **Node.JS**, [**phpMyAdmin.co**](https://phpmyadmin.co/index.php) or any another host and the error "*#2002 - Connection timed out The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)./mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out*"
`PHP version: 8.0.16 (cli)`
`phpMyAdmin version: 5.2.1`
[`Full Information`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzklv.png)
[`How I'm fill the data into phpMyAdmin.co`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G1J2.png) - In the server input I puts the domain of the project e.g.: (phpmyadmin.myusername.repl.co)

**- config.inc.php file (It was config.sample.inc.php before):**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

/* Server parameters */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '0.0.0.0';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

**- my.cnf file:**

```
[server]
datadir = /home/runner/phpmyadminserver/sql_data
user = runner
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 3306
skip-name-resolve
skip-networking = 0
pid-file = mysqld.pid
log-error = error.log
general_log_file = general.log
general_log = 1
disable-log-bin = 1
innodb-log-file-size = 4194304
lower_case_table_names = 1
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
[mysql]
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I'm trying to connect but it's not accepts the connecting.

Comment: Yes, its working on the same host but on remote it's not, in the screenshot of phpmyadmin.co I blurred the phpmyadmin.username.repl.co cause I want to be private, that's why you see it just phpmyadmin.

Comment: Confirm mysqld is listening - `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep mysqld`. If it is listening (0.0.0.0:3306), use telnet to see if you can route to it from a remote host - `telnet your.host.name 3306`. You should see a slightly _garbled_ looking message, part of which will look like the server version. If not, it is likely that there is a firewall blocking the way.

Comment: Bro, replit just supports nix environment its not supports sudo.